# Tipo de dado via socket

Tags: delphi, socket

Existe alguma maneira/truque/algoritmo que me permita saber que tipo de dado está vindo via socket? Posso enviar tanto texto como arquivos via socket, mas eu gostaria de saber o que estou recebendo para tratar de maneira diferente.
Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria socket TCP/IP? Se sim, você recebe uma "torrente" de bytes. Você tem de ter um protocolo de aplicação, conhecido dos dois lados, para saber o que está sendo recebido. Não há como você simplesmente mandar um dado via TCP, sem qualquer rotulagem, e o outro lado "adivinhar" do que se trata.

Poderia ser algo baseado em JSON, por exemplo - quando uma mensagem JSON válida é completamente recebida, você sabe que a primeira mensagem acabou, e os bytes que sobraram já fazem parte de uma segunda mensagem.

Há protocolos como SCTP que permitem mandar mensagens de forma atômica - a aplicação sempre recebe um "pacote" indivisível, e cada mensagem pode ter um rótulo, que facilita identificar o tipo da mensagem. Mas infelizmente o SCTP é pouco utilizado, o TCP é o que se usa e o protocolo de aplicação tem de carregar este fardo.

Existem inúmeras bibliotecas que fazem esse serviço - usar um canal TCP para mandar e receber mensagens indivisíveis e tipadas. XMPP é uma delas.

Comment: Obrigado @epx, criei mesmo um protocolo, que exige que antes de texto seja enviada uma string para identificar. Foi a maneria mais simples e eficaz de resolver.